# Is there a way to refresh a file that is opened by TextEdit?

Tags: textedit

As an academic, I often have to conduct "numerical experiments" by running a small computer program that outputs to a text file.
I use TextEdit to read the text file.
However, when I re-run the program, and the contents of the text file changes, I find that the contents in TextEdit do not automatically update to the new version.
In order to access the new version, I need to close the existing TextEdit window, and open the file again in TextEdit.

Is there a way to refresh the file to the new version in TextEdit?
For those of you who know about the program Vim, what I am looking for is like the command `:e[dit]` in Vim which allows one to

> Edit the current file. This is useful to re-edit the current file, when it has been changed outside of Vim.

Comment: I do not use TextEdit, but BBEdit will definitely update when edited elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I decided to try TextWrangler (the free version of BBEdit) and it also auto-refreshes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a *ugly* way of doing it, as far as I know.

Once the file has been edited just try to save it. TextEdit will prompt you saying something like:

> The document "Untitled.txt" couldn't be saved. Other application modified the file.

Giving you the choice to either **Restore** or **Save anyway**.

While **Save anyway** will keep your changes **and** save as a new version the *changes* made by the other application, **Restore** will *update* your file with these new changes.

Unless there's a specific reason to use *TextEdit* I'd recommend using any other text editor, such as [TextMate](http://macromates.com/download), which supports the automatic refresh.

Comment: TextMate is a gem.

Comment: In Macos `ventura` it is `revert` instead of `restore`. `save anyway` is an option and `save as..`

Answer (score -3):

Refresh current open file is refresh by using
 **ALT+F and R**

Comment: Isn't that a Windows set of keys?